# How to make `scikit-image` return a contiguous array without negative strides?

Tags: python, numpy, pytorch, scikit-image

I am using [Scikit-Image `imread`](https://scikit-image.org/docs/stable/api/skimage.io.html#skimage.io.imread) function for reading images for a PyTorch data loader.

I get errors from the function `ToTensor()`, saying the the strides of the numpy array are negative.
I read about it and using `somearray.copy()` solves it.

Yet, I'd like to solve it from the root. How can I force Scikit-Image to read the image into a contiguous array with regular strides?

I looked for solutions for this case and they mostly about creating a new copy of data which I want to avoid.

Those are the properties of the array:

```py
print(f'shape: {img.shape}')
print(f'dtype: {img.dtype}')
print(f'strides: {img.strides}')
```

The output:

```
shape: (4032, 3024, 3)
dtype: uint8
strides: (3, -12096, 1)
```

When I run `img.base` I get the values of the data. Though the dimensions are `(3024, 4032, 3)`

Comment: Give us some information about the array.  For example, `arr.shape`, `arr.dtype`, `arr.strides`.  If `arr.base` isn't `None`, you might show the same information for that.

Comment: @hpaulj, I added the information you wanted. By the way, `plt.imread` gives non negative strides for the image.

Comment: It IS being read contiguously.  The issue is, thanks to IBM idiocy and the OS/2 legacy, Windows Device Independent Bitmaps (.BMP) are stored upside down -- the bottom scanline is first.  Thus, to do normal ordering, you start with the last scan (which is the top) and use a negative stride.

Comment: @TimRoberts, Yet this is a `jpg` file. Not a `bmp` file. Anyhow, how can I force `imread` to give a contiguous array with no negative strides as `plt.imread` and `PIL`?

Comment: It IS contiguous.  You shouldn't have to worry about the stride.  Have you tried just USING this image?

Comment: @TimRoberts, I wrote the context, if you try to convert it to a pytorch tensor you using `To_Tensor` get an error for negative strides. Using `plt.imread` doesn't have such issue. Maybe I should submit it as a bug?

Comment: It looks like `.copy` is the only solution.  https://discuss.pytorch.org/t/torch-from-numpy-not-support-negative-strides/3663

Comment: @TimRoberts, Unless `scikit-learn` will avoid negative strides to begin with. Like `plt.imread`.

Comment: Why would they?  A solution exists.  Their output is not wrong just because it doesn't fit your needs exactly.

Comment: Because working with PyTorch is something many use and is performance sensitive. So if there is a way to optimize this path, it might be important to the users.

Answer (score 1):

I don't know a lot about image file formats, but can make some deductions from the data you provided

```
shape: (4032, 3024, 3)
dtype: uint8
strides: (3, -12096, 1)

img.base (3024, 4032, 3)
```

`img` is a `view` of its `base`.  The negative `strides[1]` means that dimension has been reversed, e.g. with a `::-1` indexing.  The fact that the largest stride is in the middle, means the first two dimensions have been swapped (`transpose(1,0,2)`).  I expect `img.base.strides` is (12096,3,1).  12096 is 3*4032.

`jpg` is a compressed format, but I assume the `base` is close in layout to the file, and this `view` is needed to conform to our normal `numpy` expectations for an array.

`img.copy()` will have the same shape, but strides will be (9072,3,1).

If `plt.imread` produces an array with that shape and strides, it may well have returned that copy rather than the view.  It's not necessarily being any more "efficient".

Think about how we print a 2d array - 1st dimension, rows, going down, 2nd, columns, going across, left to right.  But think about a common `xy` plot - `x` goes left to right, and `y` goes from bottom up.  Or look at what `np.meshgrid` says about `indexing`, 'ij' versus 'xy'.

Having the size 3 dimension last is just another convention.  That's the color 'channel', 3 for RGB, 4 adds a transparency value, and 1 for b/w.  Sometimes arrays have that dimension first.

Comment: The question is, could the decoding phase of data from the file be optimized to have a better memory layout in that context.